# How to write two variables to one text file?

Tags: r

I have two files which I want to do some calculations based on each other.

File 1:

```
conne <- file("C:\\bias.bin","rb")
cor<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

File 2:

```
conne2 <- file("C:\\me1440s.bin","rb")
bioms<- readBin(conne2, integer(), size=1,  n=1440*720, signed=F)
```

Calculate:

```
 mean=tapply(cor, bioms, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
 sd=tapply(cor, bioms, sd, na.rm=TRUE)
 min=tapply(cor, bioms, min, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Write to a text file:

```
write.table(min, "C:\\Users\\period.txt", sep="\t")
```

This will write only min to one text file. How can I write all mean, sd, and min to one text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `mean`, `sd` and `min` are the same length, you can put all variables in one data frame and then write to file.

```
write.table(data.frame(mean,sd,min), "C:\\Users\\period.txt", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 5):

In a more general sense than @Didzis's answer, you can use `append = TRUE` in the call to `write.table`. From the documentation of `write.table`:

> append: logical. Only relevant if ‘file’ is a character string.  If
>             ‘TRUE’, the output is appended to the file.  If ‘FALSE’, any
>             existing file of the name is destroyed.

So you can call `write.table` multiple times, and get all the output in one file:

```
write.table(mean, "C:\\Users\\period.txt", sep="\t")
write.table(sd, "C:\\Users\\period.txt", sep="\t", append = TRUE)
write.table(min, "C:\\Users\\period.txt", sep="\t", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Why I am getting this `Warning message:
In write.table(min, "C:\\period2.txt",  :
  appending column names to file`

Comment: I think writing them as dataframe is better because the sd , mean, will be written in the text file as different columns, while following your solution will just show each one as x and the values.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related, but if you doesn't care to write to a text file, you can use the `Rdata` R file format, which stores data in a binary, more compact way, but which is not compatible with other softwares.

You can save several objects in the same `Rdata` file this way :

```
save(obj1, obj2, obj3, file="myfile.rda")
```

Then in another R session you can do :

```
load("myfile.rda")
```

And the objects previously saved will be accessible to your R session.